# How to work different .net versions in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis

How to work different .net versions in IIS 6.0 without creating two application pools?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an application pool for 1.1 and one for 2.0. 3.5 runs on top of 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because IIS 6.0 needs an Application app pool for the different .net Version as it loads the corresponding ddl files in the background.

So you'll need an app pool for .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0+

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an app pool for .net 1.1, a separate one for 2.0 and 3.5 and a third one if you want to do 4.0 development.

Unfortunately this is the point of application pools so there is no way around it that I know of.